# Counting the balance factor for AVL trees

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

**Hello everyone!**

I can't get the idea of how we count a balance factor for nodes in AVL tree. Can somebody explain it?

Here's the code of counting the balance, that I found:

```
size_t height() const
        {
            size_t left_h = (left == nullptr) ? 0 : left->height();
            size_t right_h = (right == nullptr) ? 0 : right->height();
            return left_h < right_h ? right_h + 1 : left_h + 1;
        }

        signed char balance()
        {
            size_t left_h = (left == nullptr) ? 0 : left->height();
            size_t right_h = (right == nullptr) ? 0 : right->height();
            return right_h - left_h;
        }
```

Also, here is the example of AVL tree with counted balances:

[image: Balances of a Nodes]

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Balance_factor)

> In a binary tree, the balance factor of a node is defined to be the height difference of its two-child sub-trees.

So, in order to calculate the balance of a node, you have to calculate the heights of its children.

Let's analyze the code which calculates balance:

```
signed char balance()
{
    // calculate height of the children
    // check whether left is absent, if yes: 0, else calculate height on left 
    size_t left_h = (left == nullptr) ? 0 : left->height();
    // the same with right
    size_t right_h = (right == nullptr) ? 0 : right->height();

    // return the difference of heights of the right child and the left child
    return right_h - left_h;
}
```